# Was the video Sarah Huckabee Sanders tweeted out against Jim Acosta altered?

Tags: united-states, politics

The media was all abuzz about a video Sarah Huckabee Sanders tweeted out in regards to Jim Acosta's disbarring:

https://twitter.com/PressSec/status/1060374680991883265

Many outlets claimed that this video originated with Paul Joseph Watson/Infowars and it was altered.

Are both these claims correct?

Comment: Determining intent is off-topic here, so I removed those parts from the question. Determining if that video was actually altered is on-topic.

Comment: Removed answers and political opinions from comments.

Comment: @Oddthinking Opened a Meta-question on this subject here: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4269/22559

Comment: @MadScientist Could intent be potentially be on topic, if the experts that analyze it such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSyz1gEzbls) determine that the video was most likely manipulated to make more aggressive movements, and not due to compression and other technical issues?

Comment: @Santropedro nope, it's just off topic on Skeptics

Comment: @MadScientist - not really seeing how the video gets to that vs the original without being intentionally edited, but I guess that's not vital to this question. We can pretend it happened by magic fairy dust.

Comment: @polo Magic fairy dust is always screwing up my edits ;)

Comment: I want to add some perspective to the question. It seems that Acosta upset the president at a press conference and went to move on to another reporter. Acosta wouldn't turn over the mic and kept talking. [See original c-span footage](https://www.c-span.org/video/?c4759587/disputed-interaction-wh-aide-acosta). An intern attempted to take the mic from Acosta, but he pulled away and their arms touched. Despite claims of any assault anywhere, it seems obvious to me that Trump was particularly annoyed with Acosta, while there's a good case to make that Acosta was being unprofessional.

Comment: Original claims of it being doctored didn't fixate on an extra frame, or obviously highly subjective perceptions of nuanced differences. Instead, the claims mostly centered on missing audio and lack of context. My comment hopefully gives that much needed context.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Origins

Paul Joseph Watson ([@PrisonPlanet](https://twitter.com/PrisonPlanet)) has been [quite open](https://twitter.com/PrisonPlanet/status/1060521980615634944) about producing the video:

> The video was not "doctored" by me - all I did was zoom in on the original from the Daily Wire. I did not 'speed up' anything.

He even published a [screenshot](https://twitter.com/PrisonPlanet/status/1060521980615634944/photo/1) of his video editing session, which shows edits made in order to repeat the action in close-up, and the filename of the source video clip, `DrasJZTWwAAU5hs.mp4`.

I have not yet seen an authoritative analysis of the timeline (and I would not consider the question of alteration to be “answered” without one), but the filename indicates that the original video clip, on which Watson based his edited version, is this: [`https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/DrasJZTWwAAU5hs.mp4`](https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/DrasJZTWwAAU5hs.mp4)

This is consistent with Watson’s claim that his source material was from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/realDailyWire/status/1060227002832056320) from The Daily Wire, dated “9:46 AM - 7 Nov 2018”, which links to the same video URL.  The origin of that video clip appears to be [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ForAmerica/status/1060224093604245504) by [@ForAmerica](https://twitter.com/ForAmerica), dated “9:34 AM - 7 Nov 2018” which also has the same video URL.  The origin and history of the video is also [described by Paris Martineau writing in Wired](https://www.wired.com/story/infowars-video-white-house-cnn-jim-acosta-tweet/).

The first appearance of Watson’s edited version seems to be [his tweet](https://twitter.com/PrisonPlanet/status/1060344443616800768) dated “5:33 pm - 7 Nov 2018”.  This version runs for 15 seconds but contains only material from the original 3-second clip, with progressively zoomed and cropped replays of the “crucial moment”, which plays six times in total.  This version has poorer image quality, and alternate frames are blended together.

## Alteration

Apart from the obvious crop-zoom-loop, there is a duplicated frame just as Acosta and the woman make contact (frames 2 and 3 below). This was noted by digital forensic and image analysis expert [Hany Farid](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/farid/) in reports from [Wired](https://www.wired.com/story/infowars-video-white-house-cnn-jim-acosta-tweet/) and [The New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/news/current/the-white-houses-video-of-jim-acosta-shows-how-crude-political-manipulation-can-be).  Farid further noted:

> This could have been done intentionally, but could also be the result of transcoding that changes the frame rate

and:

> I don’t see unambiguous evidence that it has been doctored.

This repeated frame occurs in both the zoomed and unzoomed cuts in Watson’s video:

[image: frames from edited video]

There is another duplicated frame a little later (frames 2 and 3; look carefully at the woman’s hair).

[image: additional frames from edited video]

These duplicate frames appear both in the [edited video tweeted by Watson](https://twitter.com/PrisonPlanet/status/1060344443616800768) and in the [video issued by Sanders](https://twitter.com/PressSec/status/1060374680991883265), but not in the `DrasJZTWwAAU5hs.mp4` source video, frames of which are shown below:

[image: frames from original video]

That is, it does not appear that the video was altered by the White House.

So, the doubled frames could be deliberate attempts to exaggerate the action, but they could also be accidental technical glitches.  Watson himself has [repeatedly](https://twitter.com/PrisonPlanet/status/1060908625974231040) [stated](https://twitter.com/PrisonPlanet/status/1060771119416967168) that the video was not doctored, but the fact remains that the exact sequence of frames used and repeated in his video is different from the video he based his edit upon.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Most of this seems to be original research, and should be deleted. Please find references to experts doing the analysis rather than doing it yourself. (Frankly, I can't even follow it. Are the allegedly repeated frames part of Watson's publicised edit history? How do we know if they were in the original footage from the camera? Is it just from frame-rate conversions?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I wondered what level of detail was appropriate, and can see that the lack of references to expert analysis is a weakness. Would it be appropriate to supply scripts or a procedure for repeating the analysis, in addition to quoting and linking to existing expert commentary?

Comment: @Oddthinking: The repeated frames are present in the video posted by Watson, but not in the video posted by The Daily Wire that Watson gives as the source. I deliberated over whether to discuss the likelihood of frame-rate conversion as a source of "technical glitches"; I think it should be addressed (brevity be damned!), but obviously by an authority.

Comment: Should I delete the contentious material and leave it as a half-answer ("did the video originate with Paul Joseph Watson?") for now?

Comment: Duplicate frames are A) common in edit and conversion and B) hardly noticeable. You mention these duplicate frames like it means something but give no explanation how or why they do.

Comment: @fredsbend That's fair - whether the videos differ is one question; whether it was a deliberate edit is quite another.

Comment: *"the exact sequence of frames used and repeated in his video is different from the video he based his edit upon."* Naturally. He halved the framerate to make a gif. That's going to generate some duplicate frames, among other unavoidable changes.

Comment: While I get that he is claiming that he didn't intentionally manipulate the speed of the frames at certain points, it strikes me as kind of silly to claim that he didn't "doctor" the video while talking about the extensive **editing** he did to it.

Comment: @fredsbend: but Watson says he started with the "GIF" (actually the DrasJZTWwAAU5hs.mp4 file generated by Twitter), edited it in Sony Vegas, exported as an `.mt2`, and converted that to `.mp4`. According to ffprobe, DrasJZTWwAAU5hs.mp4 already has a frame rate of 343/12 (approx. 28.583) Hz, so the frame-doubling had already been done by Twitter. The conversion to scrutinise then is from the original 28.583 Hz to the 29.97 Hz in Watson's edit.

Comment: Watson's video takes 106 frames to cover what the original took 102 frames. 29.97 / (28.583) * 102 = 106.95 (rounded to 2DP), so it seems plausible to me (not a video expert) that the duplicated frames could be due to frame rate conversion.

Comment: It's not impossible that the source "GIF" was cut so that when it was frame-rate converted, that particular frame where the two people make contact would be repeated (giving the illusion of a stronger impact). This would also give plausible deniability. I am now sounding very much like a conspiracy theorist! Questions of intent and further analysis of the video editing process would require assistance from Watson himself; Dan Voshart is trying to make progress on that front: https://twitter.com/dvoshart/status/1062194828287582209.

Comment: From my own analysis of the timeline screenshot, the main five cut points align well (within one frame) with the obvious changes in the frame sequence. I don't have an explanation for the two brief additional cuts (5 or 6 frames each), as they don't appear to correspond to any significant event in the frame sequence, but they don't coincide with either of the duplicated frames noted in my answer.

Comment: @polo The word "doctor" implies stuff was done that makes it look like something else happened. I wouldn't call looping and zooming "doctored", but I would for things like color changes, speed changes, audio filters or additions, etc. These fundamentally change the video.

Comment: @screw 28.583 is a very strange framerate. Why would Twitter render an upload into that?  29.97 is a common standard. I thought I read somewhere Watson's output was 15 fps; don't know where I got that.

Comment: @fredsbend - Looping and zooming and leaving out audio, for emphasis of a tiny part of the video, removing all context, certainly makes it look quite different than the raw, unedited/undoctored footage. Much moreso than if I made everyone look a shade of pink.

Comment: @polo That's the original complaints of "doctored" I heard elsewhere. I said so in a comment on the question, but a mod deleted it. So now, here we are talking about an inconsequential duplicate frame. I've thought about answering to that effect, but it seems not just skeptics SE has lost perspective on the issue.

Comment: In other words, perhaps the question should be, did Jim Acosta assault an intern?

Comment: @fredsbend - I get that part, that it's a bit of a semantic discussion with all sides defining "doctored" to their convenience.

Comment: @fredsbend: I agree, it's a strange framerate. `ffprobe` reports 323/12 (28.58333...) in its "tbr" field, but 14.57 in its "fps" field. Dan Voshart's VLC analysis shows 14.56 FPS. I don't know if such a frame rate is normal/plausible for a GIF converted by Twitter to an MP4.

Comment: The original question was edited to remove a part about the alteration being intentional, but I can see it's still problematic. I've been trying to focus on whether Watson's edit misrepresents the timing, and steer clear of questions of intent or a judgement of the actions depicted - you could equally ask "did an intern assault Acosta?" ;) There's the additional question of whether the source video that Watson based his edit on is a faithful reproduction of the original C-Span footage.

Comment: Perhaps all we can really say is that the sequence of frames in Watson's video is not the same as his source, and we don't know if that was deliberate or the result of video conversion.

Answer (score 17):

According to the [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2018/11/08/white-house-shares-doctored-video-support-punishment-journalist-jim-acosta/), experts agree that the video is altered:

> Side-by-side comparisons support claims from fact-checkers and experts such as Jonathan Albright, research director of the Tow Center for Digital Journalism at Columbia University, who argued that crucial parts of the video appear to have been altered so as to distort the action.
>
> A frame-by-frame breakdown by Storyful, a social-media intelligence firm that verifies media content, found that the edited video included repeated frames that did not appear in the original footage. The repeated frames were shown only at the moment of contact and made Acosta’s arm movement look more exaggerated, said Shane Raymond, a journalist at Storyful.

[Arstechnica](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2018/11/ap-video-expert-says-white-house-clip-of-cnn-reporter-was-likely-doctored/) reports that two experts agree that the video was altered:

> The video is altered, Shapiro told the AP, to make Acosta's actions as he held on to the microphone look faster and more aggressive. [...] Video producer Jamison Hermann separately told The Verge that he suspected the clip was doctored after analyzing the press version of the video and the While House's version of the video frame by frame.

[Vice](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/qvqpp5/no-evidence-the-white-house-video-of-jim-acosta-was-doctored-forensic-expert-says) quotes a professor who agrees that the video is changed and gives an incorrect impression, but who thinks that there is not enough evidence that the video was "doctored":

> “From my review of the various videos of the press conference, I believe that the video tweeted by the Press Secretary is misleading but I don’t see unambiguous evidence that it has been doctored,” Farid told Motherboard via email. “A combination of a reduction in the quality of the video, a slowing-down of the video, and the particular vantage point of the CSPAN video gives the appearance that there was more contact between the reporter and the intern than there probably was. In particular, if you look at original, higher-quality videos from other vantage points you can more clearly see that while there was some contact between the reporter and intern, he did not strike her as his hand comes down.”

They quote a second expert who agrees:

> "There are duplicate frames at the moment of contact; 2 additional frames for no apparent reason but one could surmise that it could give the false impression of a split second more contact then there actually was," Smith wrote.

Kellyanne Conway also [agrees](https://www.washingtonpost.com/nation/2018/11/12/kellyanne-conway-acosta-video-thats-not-altered-thats-sped-up-they-do-it-all-time-sports/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.e7a75a8f6b83) that the video was changed ("sped up") (though she disagrees that this means that the video was "altered").

**Conclusion**: Experts agree that the video shared by Sanders is not identical to the original video, that it comes from a dubious source - an editor of the far-right, fake news website InfoWars, and that it may give a wrong impression.

Where there is disagreement is if the words "doctored", "altered", or "sped up" should be used to describe the change, and whether or not this change was deliberate (both of which are opinion-based and go to the motivation of people, and are thus not on-topic here).

Comment: It's a bit odd to note that duplicate frames were not in the original footage, when duplicate frames is an edit and conversion phenomenon, especially when lowering framerate. And at 15fps, a single frame is 0.066 seconds. Not much. It's argued that's enough to notice audio async, but as a professional video editor myself, I'd say changes in motion are negligible.

Comment: Yet, if a single frame is 0.066 seconds, a doubled frame is visible for 0.132 seconds. I would imagine that this is long enough to notice a static picture,. But then, I'm not a professional video editor, and also not a perceptual psychologist.

Comment: @schmuddi Two identical images means no movement between them. If your goal is to intentionally make motion look faster, duplicating frames would only theoretically work if you also delete some previous frames. So, assuming the change is noticeable, you'd see a "fast" movement (more like choppy) followed by a pause. In other words, it would look horrible if the goal was to speed it up.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere Watson's output was 15 fps; don't know where I got that. Seems it was 29.97, nearly double, so duplicates are even less noticeable.

Comment: An acceptable way to increase video speed is to increase framerate but not add any frames. The video will have a shorter run time, but will be sped up.